# Show that $1$ is a repelling fixed point for $f(x)=x^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

**Exercise:** Let $f(x) = x^2$. Show that $1$ is a repelling fixed point of $f(x)$.

*What I've tried:* I think I need to show that $\left|x^2 - 1\right| >\left|x - 1\right|$ whenever $\left|x - 1\right| <\delta$ for some $\delta>0$, because this would mean that $f^n(x)\not\to 1$ for $x \neq 1$. We have that $\left|x^2 - 1\right| =\left|(x-1)(x+1)\right| = \left|x-1\right|\left|x+1\right| > \left|x-1\right|$ whenever $\left|x+1\right|> 1$ and whenever $\left|x - 1\right| >\dfrac{\left|x-1\right|}{\left|x+1\right|}\Leftrightarrow \left|x-1\right| <\left|x+1\right|$. I don't really what to do from here. I know that $\left|x+1\right| > 1$ holds if $x\geq 0$ or when $x\leq -2$ which would mean that $\left|x-1\right|<1$ or  $\left|x - 1\right|\geq 3$, if I'm not mistaken.

**Question:** How should I approach (in general) inequalities with absolute value signs? How should I solve this exercise? I'm often unable to show where inequalities with absolute values hold, even though they should be rather easy...

Thanks!

Comment: It is sufficient that f'(1)= 2 is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general way to approach inequalities with absolute values.
In this particular case, you did all the necessary computations:
$$
|f(x)-1|>|x-1|
$$
whenever $|x+1|>1$ and $x\neq1$.
This means, in particular, that whenever $x>0$, you know that iterating $f$ takes you further away from $1$.
If you start with any value $x>0$ which is not exactly $1$, the iterates will take you further away from $1$ and convergence to $1$ is impossible.